# How to add the list value to the networkx nodes by using "for loop"?

Tags: python, for-loop

I tried to add list value [weight] to the networkx nodes [7 nodes] as a weight.
But when I iterate through the value, its does not accounts the first value of the list to the for loop and says "**IndexError: list index out of range**"

```
weight = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]

for v in G.nodes():
G.nodes[v]["clb"] = weight[v]
```

Could you please suggest me a solution for this!
Thank You

Comment: because you are using v as index for weight list, v is a node id that can be anything not necessarily a list index

Comment: also you can make a dictionary of like **{node_id : score}** to directly set node attribute using [set_node_attributes(G, values, name=None)](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enumerate index, currently you are passing **v** as index for weight list. which is a node id and node id can be '0' (first index of list)  or anything else.

**code example:**

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.complete_graph(7)
weight = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]

print(G.nodes(data= True))

for index, node in enumerate(G.nodes()):
    G.nodes[node]["clb"] = weight[index]

print(G.nodes(data= True))
```

[image]